# Configure Hibernate in Spring Boot to ignore certain classes marked with Entity which are imported via dependency

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

In my project I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` with `spring-boot-starter-webflux`

I have various 
@Entity notations being correctly recognised by hibernate, however, in one module I depend on another module in the project not related to the webserver, the structure is something like below:

```
       ROOT MODULE
       /         \
  Dependency   Dependant
 (non web app) (web app with spring boot jpa)
```

This non web module also makes use of hibernate and @Entity.
When booting the spring server, hibernate in the web directory seems to be trying to load the classes marked @Entity in the other module, this is causing weird issues and a data leak.

How can I tell hibernate to only look in the current module and to ignore the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use @EntityScan annotation to tell spring where to find your entities.
More details on the [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/domain/EntityScan.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-data-access)